# Entity Framework: Set default limit for queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I've just started working on some code that uses EF6 (Code First) and quite badly written. I discovered many cases where several thousand rows were returned from queries before they were paged (paging was applied after enumerating over the queryable).

Is there a way to intercept all `IQueryable` executions *by default* and apply `.Take(128)`?

Comment: How does the code access EF context? Directly using the `DBSet` property?

Comment: Code First! So `DbContext` + `DbSet<T>`

Comment: I have not tried it, but you could try use the DbInterception.
More info on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have bad code, the best you can do is to fix it of course, and not by adding weird workarounds..

One option you could try to use as weird workaround is (relatively new?) `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` which allows you to rewrite the expression tree at the "expressions" level:

```
public class LimitInterceptor : IDbCommandTreeInterceptor
{
    public void TreeCreated(DbCommandTreeInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
    {
        if (interceptionContext.OriginalResult.DataSpace == DataSpace.SSpace)
        {
            var queryCommand = interceptionContext.Result as DbQueryCommandTree;
            if (queryCommand != null)
            {
                var newQuery = queryCommand.Query.Accept(new LimitVisitor());
                interceptionContext.Result = new DbQueryCommandTree(
                    queryCommand.MetadataWorkspace,
                    queryCommand.DataSpace,
                    newQuery);
            }
        }
    }
}

// rewrite the tree - needs adjustment probably, looks like a very naive implementation (?)
public class LimitVisitor : DefaultExpressionVisitor
{
    public override DbExpression Visit(DbScanExpression expression)
    {
        // here we go!
        return DbExpressionBuilder.Limit(expression, 128);
    }
}

// will be automatically picked up
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
        AddInterceptor(new LimitInterceptor());
    }
}
```

Found about about `IDbCommandTreeInterceptor` from [this post](http://romiller.com/tag/idbcommandtreeinterceptor/).
There is also another interception option (but it is for already-generated sql) `IDbCommandInterceptor`, maybe you'll be able to make some use of it.

Comment: Nice one! I'll report back when I've tested it. Actually I thought of throwing an exceptions if fetched results exceed 128 to prompt developers to fix it and THEN adding this code to have the default limit there for further protection. What would be the best place to intercept and throw the exception?

Comment: No idea actually. At this stage, it's still an expression, so the result is not known yet. Maybe you could use IDbCommandInterceptor.ReaderExecuted instead (the one which works at SQL level) to see how many results are returned and if too many then trow.

Comment: Thank you. I'll add it to your answer when I get round to it.